# ¿Cómo filtrar por termino en angular 4?

Tags: ionic, angular

estoy intentando filtrar por un id concreto una lista de elementos (tours), lo hago de la siguiente manera:

El pipe que utilizo:

```
filterByCity(id, tours){
if (id==''){
  return [];
}
return tours.filter((item) => {

  console.log(item);
  if (!item.city) {
    return false
  } else {
    return item.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(id.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  }
});
```

}

Desde donde lo llamo:

```
 setFilteredItems() {
this.finalTours = this.dataService.filterByCity(this.param, this.tours);
console.log(this.finalTours);
```

}

El param es la id de la ciudad, y this.tours todos los tours, necesito que el pipe me devuelva todos los tours que tengan tour.city = param, pero no me devuelve nada.

Answer (score 0):

La comparación que esta dentro del filter esta buscando dentro de la cadena de id, prueba solo comparando con el ===

```
filterByCity(id, tours){
  if (id==''){
   return [];
  }
  return tours.filter((item) => item.city && item.city.toLowerCase() === id.toLowerCase())
});
```

Si el id no coincide o city es undefined (que no deberia si es un identificador unico) no regresará nada por lo que no es necesario retornar false en ese caso.